# Editor for Django, Angular and Ionic?

Tags: javascript, python, text-editor, ide, angularjs

I'm working with the frameworks Django, Angular and Ionic. I am developing a simple data driven web application and mobile app.

I started by using PyCharm for Django and that was OK. But when I started with Angular, PyCharm didn't give much help at all, so I downloaded WebStorm. It feels like a small burden to have two editors. I would prefer to have one editor that has syntax highlighting and syntax checking and parameter help for both Python and JavaScript.

What editor do you recommend based on this description?

Comment: Visual Studio Code would be the answer nowadays

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you another software from Jetbrains: [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/).

- it's type of "mixture" from WebStorm, PyCharm and other IDEs, so it supports both JS (AngularJS) and Python
- it has a large base of plugins, so you can download another syntax highlithers
- it has 30-days free trial
- for students/teachers, education, open source projects etc. it's free, another licenses are paid (but individual is cheaper)
- support for web and mobile apps